# Importing a CSV list to an array structure in C

Tags: c

So i'm working on a class project that is going to manage a stores inventory. The program will need to remove/add products as well as update stock counts. When the program runs the structure array needs to be initialized by a inventory file that its values are separated by commas which saves all the data after each use.

Here is the file data.

```
1000,1.49,3.79,10,0,Fish Food
2000,0.29,1.59,100,1,Angelfish
2001,0.09,0.79,200,1,Guppy
5000,2.40,5.95,10,0,Dog Collar (Large)
6000,49.99,129.99,3,1,Dalmatian Puppy
```

Here is the structure layout.

```
    struct inventory_s
    {
      int productNumber;
      float mfrPrice;
      float retailPrice;
      int numInStock;
      char liveInv;
      char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ];
    };
```

And here is the code

```
int fileData()
{

FILE* pFile;
char *buf = malloc(MAX_INVENTORY); // MAX INVENTORY = 50
char *info;
if ( ( pFile = fopen( "inventory.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) //Reading a file
{
    printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
}

int i = 0;
while (fgets(buf, MAX_INVENTORY, pFile) != NULL)
{
    if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n'))
        buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';

    info = strtok(buf, ",");
    inventory[i].productNumber = atoi(info);

    info = strtok(buf, ",");
    inventory[i].mfrPrice = atof(info);

     info = strtok(NULL, ",");
    inventory[i].retailPrice = atof(info);

      info = strtok(NULL, ",");
    inventory[i].numInStock = atoi(info);

    info = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(inventory[i].liveInv, info);

    info = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(inventory[i].productName, info);


    printf("%i, %f, %f, %i, %s, %s \n", inventory[i].productNumber , inventory[i].mfrPrice, inventory[i].retailPrice , inventory[i].numInStock, inventory[i].liveInv, inventory[i].productName );

    i++;
}

fclose(pFile);
return 0;
}
```

Right now I dont get anything if I run the code, but if I run only up to the first initialization

```
info = strtok(buf, ",");
inventory[i].productNumber = atoi(info);
```

I get all the first values assigned correctly.

Comment: Don't strip the trialing `'\n'` and change your delimiter list to `",\n"`.

Comment: OT: `printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );` but you continue executing the code ... I suggest to `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or return from the function in this case.

Comment: Sidenote: Never use floating point for precise values/calculations. Use integers scaled to the smallest possible uint (e.g. cents) instead.

Comment: I changed it like  user3121023 suggested and got the values assigned, but I'm still having problems with the final two char values.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, It is hard to tell without seeing your entire code where the issue may be. However, the thing that jumps out is there is no need to strip the trailing `'\n'` from `buf` before calling `strtok`. You are better served by using a delimiter of `",\n"` and letting `strtok` handle the final string in each line.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { PRODUCTNAME_SZ = 32, MAXINV = 128, MAXC = 512 };

typedef struct {
    int productNumber;
    float mfrPrice;
    float retailPrice;
    int numInStock;
    char liveInv;
    char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ];
} inventory_s; 

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    inventory_s *inv = NULL;
    char buf[MAXC] = "", *delim = ",\n";
    size_t allocsz = MAXINV, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(inv = malloc (sizeof *inv * allocsz))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p = buf;
        size_t val = 0;     /* tokenize line with strtok */
        for (p = strtok (p, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim))
            switch (val) {  /* switch controls assignment */
                case 0 :    inv[idx].productNumber = (int)strtol (p, NULL, 10);
                            val++; break;
                case 1 :    inv[idx].mfrPrice = strtof (p, NULL);
                            val++; break;
                case 2 :    inv[idx].retailPrice = strtof (p, NULL);
                            val++; break;
                case 3 :    inv[idx].numInStock = (int)strtol (p, NULL, 10);
                            val++; break;
                case 4 :    inv[idx].liveInv = (char)strtol (p, NULL, 10);
                            val++; break;
                case 5 :    strncpy (inv[idx].productName, p, PRODUCTNAME_SZ);
                            inv[idx].productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ-1] = 0; break;
            }
        if (val != 5) {     /* validate all struct members filled */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: incomplete parse of values line: %zu\n",
                     idx+1);
            return 1;
        }

        if (++idx == allocsz) { /* realloc when allocsz reached */
            void *tmp = realloc (inv, (allocsz + MAXINV) * sizeof *inv);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                break;  /* leave read loop preserving exhisting data in inv */
            }
            inv = tmp;
            allocsz += MAXINV;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("%5d  %6.2f  %7.2f  %4d  %d  %s\n", inv[i].productNumber,
                inv[i].mfrPrice, inv[i].retailPrice, inv[i].numInStock,
                inv[i].liveInv, inv[i].productName);

    free (inv); /* free allocated memory */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** if your `liveInv` value is really just a single digit, then you can replace `(char)strtol (p, NULL, 10);` with simply `*p - '0';`.

(You may need to set `PRODUCTNAME_SZ` larger depending on your full dataset)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inventory <dat/inventory.txt
 1000    1.49     3.79    10  0  Fish Food
 2000    0.29     1.59   100  1  Angelfish
 2001    0.09     0.79   200  1  Guppy
 5000    2.40     5.95    10  0  Dog Collar (Large)
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Java Programmer but Now Building Its so called Java Collections in C &C++. This code is a Part of My Project "Big Data Analysis Using C & C++".

I already had the code, so, modified for your data. It can take any no. of columns. Just pass opened file pointer & separation type.

You can get a particular column just by removing all the if part of j (ex. if(j==1), etc) to your particular column. Most people forget this. :-D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int MAX=1000; // Size of Single String
void analyse(FILE *fp, char separation) {
/* fp is file pointer (already opened)
 * separation is how data is separated (' ' or '\t' or ',')
 */
    char str[MAX],ch;
    int i=-1;
    long j=0;
// J is Column. This Can Be Applied For Any No. of Columns.
    cout<<"Reading File.."<<endl;
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF) {
        i++;
        if(ch!=separation && ch!='\n')
            str[i] = ch;
        else {
            str[i] = '\0';
            if(ch == separation || ch == '\n') {
                j++;
            }
// At Each if of j, you can write you code to store them.
            if(j == 1) {
                cout<<"Product No. : "<<str<<endl;
            }
            if(j == 2) {
                cout<<"MFR Price : "<<str<<endl;
            }
            if(j == 3) {
                cout<<"Retail : "<<str<<endl;
            }
            if(j == 4) {
                cout<<"Num in Stock : "<<str<<endl;
            }
            if(j == 5) {
                cout<<"LiveInv : "<<str<<endl;
            }
            if(j == 6) {
                cout<<"Product Name : "<<str<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
            if(ch == '\n')
                j = 0;
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Reading Completed.."<<endl;
}
```